# Laravel send() with data in email blade?

Tags: laravel, email

My Laravel 8 App can send emails by using my own template called 'supportmail' but how do I pass the data to that template? Currently I only get an empty mail with correct sender ($data['from'] and subject ($data['subject']).

in the Controller I have:

*EmailController.php:*

```
[..] 

$data = [
              'subject' => $request->request_title,
              'email' => 'support@mysite.com',
              'content' => $request->request_description,
              'from' =>$request->request_email
            ];    
    
    Mail::send('supportmail', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
              $message->to($data['email'])->from($data['from'])
              ->subject($data['subject']);
            });
```

how do I get the $data['content'] (= mail text) into my supportmail template?

*supportmail.blade.php:*

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', ' - Support-E-Mail')

@section('content')
<p>CONTENT HERE</p>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it, the blade gets the content with $content:

```
@section('content')
<p>{!! $content !!}</p>
@endsection
```